# ILP constraints for connectivity in a matrix

Tags: dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I'm trying to use ILP to solve the following problem:
A series of connected nodes are provided. For the example below, a is only connected to b, b is connected to both a and c, c is connected to both b and d, and d is only connected to c. I want to place the four nodes in a matrix to minimize the required columns while maintaining connectivity. The constraint is the row number of the matrix, in this example, the row number is 3.

[image]

Two possible solutions are below, where the column number is reduced to 2:

[image]        [image]

An invalid solution is below, where a cannot connect to d:

[image]

To use ILP, I assign each node with a row and column value. For example, a is (Xa,Ya).
The constraints can be set as:

`Ya, Yb, Yc, Yd <= 3    Xb + Yb - Xa - Ya = 1 or -1    Xc + Yc - Xb - Yb = 1 or -1    Xd + Yd - Xc - Yc = 1 or -1`

I have two questions.

1. Is the 1 or -1 constraint valid for an ILP solver?
2. The above constraints do not avoid the illegal connection, e.g., the connection between a and d. A potential solution is:

`Xc + Yc - Xa - Ya > 1 or < -1    Xd + Yd - Xa - Ya > 1 or < -1    Xd + Yd - Xb - Yb > 1 or < -1`

However, this solution seems not scalable to the input variable size. Is there a better way to model this?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no code here, so post on Operations Research instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

"*Is the 1 or -1 constraint valid for an ILP solver?"* You could implement

```
 Xb + Yb - Xa - Ya = 1 or -1
```

as

```
 Xb + Yb - Xa - Ya = 2δ - 1
 δ ∈ {0,1}   (a binary variable)
```